# How to deal with this when I use numpy.array() to deal with 'list'？

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```
import cv2
import numpy

list_pixel=[]
list_label=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        list_pixel.append(cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\kimcho\\Desktop\\testdata\\testdata_"+str(i)+"_0"+str(j)+".png",0))
        list_label.append(i)
    j=0
list_pixel.pop(0)
list_label.pop(0)
list_pixel=numpy.array(list_pixel)
print(list_pixel)
print(list_pixel.shape)
print(list_pixel[0].shape)
```

How to deal with this  when I use numpy.array() to deal with 'list'？I wanna make datasets by imitating keras.But,the datasets I made didn't satisfy me.I want it to act like keras,to return a value like this:

[image]

It can return a value of(60000,28,28)

But as for my datasets,it can only return like this:

[image]

Only return a value of(99,)—— I got 99 pictures and I want to load their pixel into list_pixel

Here is my code:

[image]

Hoping anyone can help me solve this problem.Deeply thank you!!!

Comment: Would you please type your code here, instead of putting screenshots?

Comment: sorry,this is my first time to use stackoverflow.I dont know how you edit it like a code format to show it in a screen

Comment: import cv2
import numpy

list_pixel=[]
list_label=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        list_pixel.append(cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\kimcho\\Desktop\\testdata\\testdata_"+str(i)+"_0"+str(j)+".png",0))
        list_label.append(i)
    j=0
list_pixel.pop(0)
list_label.pop(0)
numpy.array(list_pixel)
print(list_pixel)
print(list_pixel.shape)
print(list_pixel[0].shape)

Comment: Please put your code in the question, NOT in a comment. It is really hard to read this way.

Comment: My bad,sir.That's all right there.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [`cv2.imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) you already load the image as a numpy array.

A simple approach to it is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

list_label = np.arange(0, 10)
path = "C:\\Users\\kimcho\\Desktop\\testdata\\testdata_{0}_0{1}.png"
list_pixel = np.array([
    cv2.imread(path.format(i, j), 0) for i in range(0, 10)
    for j in range(0, 10)
])
```

Let's try it on a simple scenario: we suppose there is just an image *28x28* in size, such as this one:

[image: Random 28x28 image]

Let's say it is in the path `my/path/image.png`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

list_label = np.arange(0, 10)
path = "my/path/image.png"
list_pixel = np.array([
    cv2.imread(path,0) for i in range(0, 10)
    for j in range(0, 10)
])
```

When running `list_pixel.shape` you get `(100, 28, 28)`.

Comment: sorry,sir. When I use your method and use "print(list_pixel.shape)", it only shows me that its shape is (100,),which still not satisfies my need.I wanna it to be like (100,28,28) and I dont figure out a way to do that.SO, do you have another idea?

Comment: I have added a working example. Are you sure all your images are *28x28*? Typically shapes such as (x,) in matrices are caused by different sizes in rows, so that they are treated as a list instead than as a matrix.

Comment: all the picture is 28x28. But however the numbers of the picture is not correct,which caused this error.Thank you for giving me a hand.

Comment: If this answer has solved your issue you should consider marking it as accepted. Furthermore, you should consider cleaning up and reformatting your question to clearify what is exactly the issue you faced and asked help for, removing the images.